# Как показывает себя Photoshop в linux?

Tags: linux, photoshop

Решил поставить себе систему *Linux*, для удобной работы с консолью.

Часто делаю верстку и такой вопрос, как с этим дружит Линукс? Я знаю что можно запускать сам *PSD* файл через разные программы.

Вопрос в том, что это действительно работает без багов, правильно показывает, и может экспортировать без каких либо проблем все файлы?

Comment: Работаю с ubuntu в фотошопе (Правда редко) Пока никаких проблем не встречал, все файлы загружаются корректно. Хотя у Вас, в силу специфики, может какие-то экзотичные.

Comment: если экспортировать и немножко подправить - достаточно gimp. если заниматься монтажом и ретушью, то его не хватит

Answer (score 3):

Как ведет себя Фотошоп на Линуксах лучше всего читать тут.

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17

Версии отмеченные как Gold - работают и на них можно творить, но прийдется смириться с небольшими багами. Подробнее читайте в репортах. Такие версии лучше ставить через [playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-3066-Adobe_Photoshop_CC_2015.html), который сам настроит систему для работы.

Версия CS5 (12.0) отмеченна как Platinum - значит можно просто поставить и пользоваться.

Answer (score 1):

В wine нормально работают CS5/6 иногда наблюдаются баги в PSD с большим набором слоев, где баг - отображаемая черная область в месте расположения слоя. По факту - относительно комфортно можно работать.